# Rails: making records expire

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to expire articles after a saved date has been reached, i.e.:

```
@articles = Article.where(:semiretirement => Date.today)
```

I know that that doesn't work, but how would I write `after` instead of equals?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
@articles = Article.where('semiretirement <= ?', Date.today)
```

This will find all articles whose `semiretirement` date is less than today's date. I believe that would be what you would want in order to expire articles that have passed a given date.

Comment: Perfect! So simple. I wanted that inverted (`@articles = Article.where('semiretirement >= ?', Date.today)`) but that's the solution. Thanks so much.